# How to schedule a Cron job on the Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

Does anybody know of a barebones example for scheduling a Cron job on the Google Cloud Platform?

I have a simple python script (developed in a virtualenv in visual code) and I'm struggling to follow the examples provided by google.

The script make use of the Google Cloud client libraries (like `google.cloud.storage` and `google.cloud.bigquery`).

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What about https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-functions-scheduling-cron-5657c2ae5212

Answer (score 2):

You can now use Google Cloud Scheduler which is a fully managed (and cheap!) and much easier than setting up 'proper' Cron jobs. You can find it here: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it would be to

1. create a VM in the Compute Engine - [read this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux)
2. connect to your instance - [read this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux#connect_to_your_instance)
3. set up your cron job by modify the /etc/crontab file: `$ nano /etc/crontab`

When you are actually interested in starting a process once a new file is uploaded to the Storage, then you could look into setting up a Cloud Function which would do that: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage